# Load RDD from name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark, you can do `setName` on a RDD.

Is it possible to load a RDD from the name ?

Like `spark.loadRDD(name)` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such option, because the names are not unique identifiers. There are just a method to attach additional information that will be showed in the UI or debugs string.

It is perfectly fine to have:

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3)).setName("foo")
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(4, 5, 6)).setName("foo")
```

and Spark wouldn't "know" which RDD to return.

Additionally there Spark doesn't track RDDs in general. Only objects that are cached or persisted in other ways, are "known" to Spark.

Comment: Thanks ! But it is possible with dataframe, right ? You can createTable and query table if I remember correctly.